# How to proceed with applying for UK Standard Visitor Visa for my family if primary is applying later

Tags: visas, uk, standard-visitor-visas, applications, family

Me and my family are planning on taking a vacation to the UK soon (end of June '19). Two of my children are US citizens so they do not need visas, but me, my wife, and my oldest son are all Indian citizens + green card holders, so therefore need to apply for UK standard visitor visas. We're applying from NY.

My question was, since I am the primary that provides for my son and wife, us three would all submit separate applications but only I would provide the financial documents. It's my understanding that the entire family should apply together by writing each other's reference numbers in each person's applications, and that we do not need to submit the same documents over and over again. However, due to travelling reasons, I will not be able to apply for the visa till around a week before our trip. Therefore, I will have to get an expedited process done for my UK visa.

My wife and son however can apply right now ASAP, but since I as the primary cannot apply till later, how should my wife and son go about applying? Especially when it comes to the financial documents and whatnot. I definitely do not want them to wait to apply with me because then I will have to pay for expediting for them as well.

Thanks for any help!!

Comment: Related question https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/135018/why-are-uk-visa-biometrics-appointments-suspended-at-uscis-application-support-c

Comment: Ignoring the problem with submitting UK visa applications right now, why wouldn't you submit your financial documents with your wife's application?

Comment: @mkennedy I can likely do that yes, but is that an issue if family members are advised to apply together? If I were to submit my financial documents for my wife and son, would I mention in the online application that they have no income and that I will be paying for their entire trip? And would I need some sort of letter stating I confirm that I am paying for the entire trip? Thanks.