# Do we take all supporting documents to ACS-USCIS biometric screening for UK Visa

Tags: uk, standard-visitor-visas

We understand at the ACS center here in US they are going to do the biometeric screening, but are confused if we are to take all supporting documents with us? I have searched the site here and unable to get clarity on that important question. We go tomorrow.

Interesting as an aside, learned that when using UPS to send in our documents we are to use a bubble envelope.

Comment: Do you know if the ACS centers have started processing UK biometrics ? They had stopped processing UK biometrics last month https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/135018/why-are-uk-visa-biometrics-appointments-suspended-at-uscis-application-support-c

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [special instructions for applying for a UK visa in the USA](https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/usa-apply-for-a-uk-visa/apply-for-a-uk-visa-in-the-usa) state:

> When you visit the ASC for your biometrics appointment, please take your current passport, a print out of your application form and a copy of your biometric confirmation receipt. You can print your receipt when you apply online.

Comment: I think it's important for the OP to understand that the biometrics appointment at the ASC is not an interview, nor is the ASC a visa service. The ASC has no interest in all your various supporting documents, since it's your responsibility to send them to the appropriate UK consulate/embassy.